# How do I flatten a python/pandas pivot table and manipulate the column names?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm looking to flatten this pivot table, but I'm unable to figure out a way to remove/hide/drop the multi-indexed row of "ID".

Relevant Code:

```
df = df [['B1','B2','B3','B4']]
df = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['BUCKET'],index=['ID'],columns=['TYPE'],aggfunc=len,fill_value='',margins=True)
```

Which yields:

```
      BUCKET
TYPE  B1     B2       B3      B4
ID
1     236    data1    data2   data3   
2     323    data4    data5   data3
3     442    data6    data2   data4
4     543    data8    data2   data3
5     676    data1    data8   data4
```

The following line gets me a step closer by dropping the first row

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Which yields:

```
TYPE  B1     B2       B3      B4
ID
1     236    data1    data2   data3   
2     323    data4    data5   data3
3     442    data6    data2   data4
4     543    data8    data2   data3
5     676    data1    data8   data4
```

I need to further flatten the pivot table and remove the "TYPE" row heading, replace it with "ID", and hide/drop the previous "ID" row so it's look cleans and tidy like this:

```
ID    B1     B2       B3      B4
1     236    data1    data2   data3   
2     323    data4    data5   data3
3     442    data6    data2   data4
4     543    data8    data2   data3
5     676    data1    data8   data4
```

I've tried manipulating the columns/rows with these, but to no avail... suggestions?  Thank you!

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID'])
results.columns = results.columns.get_level_values(1)
pivot_table.values.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Comment: `df = df.drop('column_name', 1)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use new function in pandas `0.18.0` - [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) for removing column name and then maybe [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df
TYPE   B1     B2     B3     B4
ID                            
1     236  data1  data2  data3
2     323  data4  data5  data3
3     442  data6  data2  data4
4     543  data8  data2  data3
5     676  data1  data8  data4

print df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
     B1     B2     B3     B4
ID                          
1   236  data1  data2  data3
2   323  data4  data5  data3
3   442  data6  data2  data4
4   543  data8  data2  data3
5   676  data1  data8  data4

print df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
   ID   B1     B2     B3     B4
0   1  236  data1  data2  data3
1   2  323  data4  data5  data3
2   3  442  data6  data2  data4
3   4  543  data8  data2  data3
4   5  676  data1  data8  data4
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the name of the index for your columns, you can just assign `None` to it:

```
df.columns.name = None
```

Should work